Python code giving different ouputs for a function call when input taking from the python console or terminal
The following code is generating two different output if executed in console(>>> ) or from a function.py file ($ python3 function.py).
1 def test():
2     print("I am happy")
3     return "avc"
4
5 a = test()
6 print(a)
7 print(test())

Terminal output:
If function.py  is executed from the terminal ($ python3 function.py). The output will be:
# Output from print(a) line 6 in terminal
I am happy
avc 

# Output from print(test()) line 7 in terminal
I am happy
avc

Console output:
If the same code is executed from the console, the output from line 6 and line 7 will be:
>>> def test():
...     print('I am happy')
...     return "avc"
... 
>>> a = test()
I am happy
>>> print(a)
avc        # Output from print(a) line 6 in console
>>> print(test())
I am happy # Output from print(test()) line 7 in console
avc        # Output from print(test()) line 7 in console

I tried to print(a) and print(test()) in console & terminal. I was expecting similar result, but the outputs were different . If the code is supposed to be executed line by line then the output from the terminal and console should be similar. I just can grab my head around this one: Why print(a) & print(test()) output are different in terminal and console. Thanks

I don't see any difference between the efffect of your "Terminal output" and "Console output", just that of course in the transscript from the Console output, we see the commands you have entered interspersed with the output.

In terminal, print(a) & print(test())  both output: I am happy/avc. In Console, print(a) output: avc and print(test()) output: I am happy/avc. The difference is clearly stated in the output from terminal and console. Hope this clarify it. Or just run the code yourself if possible. Thanks

Of course the console also echoes the commands which you enter; otherwise you would have to enter them blindly.  When you do a a=test() both print only I am happy. When you later do a print(a), both print avc. Just erase from your posting the console prompt starting with >>>, you will see the exact same sequence of output.

in fact, the behavior is the same whether you run the code in a terminal or console, but because of the computer's high processing speed, the difference might not be noticeable in the terminal. In the console, each line you input prints the output and waits for the next line.
def test():
    print('I am happy')
    return "avc"

When you create a variable of your function like this:
a = test()

The function test will be called immediately, so I am happy will be printed, and the return value "avc" will be assigned to the variable a.
If you want to assign the function itself to a variable without executing it immediately, you should do:
a = test

Then, when you want to call the function and print its result, you can use:
print(a())
print(test())

The output will be:
I am happy
avc
I am happy
avc


Thanks @Javad for the reply.  Just some clarifications: 1/ My terminal output is what is expected from the program. The console output is the one that is different. 2/ This is a tiny program with a  small output, so the  high processing speed will not prevent the ouput to be visible. So I doubt that the processing speed is responsible  for the difference, have you try to run the code?

What I mean by high processing speed is not related to the size of the program. In both terminal and console, the process is the same: first, print "I am happy," then return the function value.
In the first example: a = test()
"I am happy" prints immediately, and "avc" is assigned to a but not shown until you print a.
In the second example: print(test())
The function test is called, "I am happy" prints, and "avc" is printed immediately after.
Although the behavior is the same, the console runs line by line, making the output appear sequentially.

I never imply that the high processing speed was related to the size of the program. My question is focused on the output difference which are seriously doubt is related to the high processing speed in this case. Thanks for the reply.
